# When a very high intensity electric field is applied to a very compact conducting material are electrons emitted out of it?

Tags: electrostatics

Normally/Usually the net electric field inside a conductor is zero as the electrons and charged particles rearrange themselves in response to a field. My question is, what happens when a high intensity field is applied to a conducting material that is very small? Due to the size of the thing will the charges be unable to fully attain equilibrium due to repulsion and so instead the entire thing moves further from the source producing the field? Or are charged particles emitted from it? What do you think?

Comment: High fields on macro surfaces rip charged particles (ions or electrons) from the material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_electron_emission

Comment: The effect was used extensively to make cathode ray tubes for TV, computer monitors etc.. Also in thermionics for over a century. Worth looking into the background.